# Nesting navigators in React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm making an app in which I have more than one type of navigation, but I'm not sure how to implement it until now, my apps only had one type of navigation. I tried to read the react-navigation docs that talked about this particular implementation, but I couldn't do it. Can someone help me?

So you guys understand, I'm trying to implement a Stack navigator inside a Tab navigator so that when the user clicks on a point in a map, a details page shows up to him.

Here's what I tried to do

```
import React from 'react'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import { Map } from '../pages/Map'
import { Detail } from '../pages/Detail'

import FiIcon from '@expo/vector-icons/Feather'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export const UsersRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <NavigationContainer>
                <Tab.Navigator 
                    initialRouteName='Mapa'
                    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
                        let iconName;
            
                        if (route.name === 'Mapa') {
                            iconName = 'map'
                        } else if (route.name === 'Pesquisar') {
                            iconName = 'search'
                        } else {
                            iconName = 'user'
                        }
            
                        return <FiIcon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
                        },
                    })}
                    tabBarOptions={{
                        activeTintColor: 'black',
                        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
                    }}
                >
                    <Tab.Screen name='Mapa' component={Map} />
                    <Tab.Screen name='Pesquisar' component={() => <Text>Search</Text>} />
                    <Tab.Screen name='Perfil' component={() => <Text>Profile</Text>} />
                </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>

        <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
                    <Stack.Screen name='Mapa' component={Map} />
                    <Stack.Screen name='Detalhes' component={Detail} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: are you getting a problem while implementing stack navigator inside a tab navigator? For showing detail while pressing `Modal` is a good option.

Comment: This page will contain a lot of things, and it would be better if I made a whole Secreen for it, instead of a Modal

Comment: So what is your problem when you press on the button that navigates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
const MapaStack = () => (
   <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Mapa" component={MapaScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="AnyScreen" componnent="AnyScreen" />
   </Stack.Navigator>
); 

const Tabs = () => (
   <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Mapa" component={MapaStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Pesquisar" component={PesquisarScreen} />
   </Tab.Navigator>
);

// you could use Tabs directly instead of AppStack but there can be more requirements...
const AppStack = () => (
   <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Tabs" component="Tabs" />
   </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Basically, you can pass Navigators instead of Screens as `component` prop. And you need to use `AppStack` inside `NavigationContainer`. You need to think carefully before implementing the navigators because hierarchy is important as it states [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#parent-navigators-ui-is-rendered-on-top-of-child-navigator).